# I can't change a variable "max_execution_time"

Tags: mysql, vbscript, timeout, odbc

I change the `max_execution_time` variable from MySQL to 60000, but when I make a query using ODBC Driver in VBScript the result remains as default 30000.

**Queries used to change the value of the variable:**

```sql
SET max_execution_time = 60000;
SET GLOBAL max_execution_time = 60000;
SET SESSION max_execution_time = 60000;
```

**Queries Used in VBScript with ODBC:**

```sql
show variables like '%max_execution%';
```

I expect the output 60000, but the actual output is 30000.

I am using MySQL Server 5.7 on a Windows Server 2016.

**Note:** This problem only happens with ODBC, because I did the same test with PHP and return value was 60000.

Anyone have any idea what that might be?

**Update:**

This is the script I'm using as a test:

```vb
Dim strCon

strCon = "DRIVER = {MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver}; SERVER = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx; PORT = 3306; DATABASE = zadmin; USER = xxxx; PASSWORD = xxx; OPTION = 3; MULTI_STATEMENTS = 1;"

Dim oCon: Set oCon = WScript.CreateObject ("ADODB.Connection")
Dim oRs: Set oRs = WScript.CreateObject ("ADODB.Recordset")
oCon.Open strCon

Set oRs = oCon.Execute ("show variables like '% max_execution_time%';")

While Not oRs.EOF
    WScript.Echo oRs.Fields (1) .Value
    oRs.MoveNext
Wend
oCon.Close

Set oRs = Nothing
Set oCon = Nothing
```

Comment: Have you made a new OBDC connection since you changed the variable? Using a `SET GLOBAL` only affects connections made after the `SET` command is run and `SET SESSION` only affects the current session.

Comment: Yes. I've made a new connection. But the result still remains 30000.

Comment: You probably need to set the value in your config file rather than just running a `SET`. `SET GLOBAL` will get reset after the server is restarted.

Comment: The code you posted is broken (missing double quote at the end of the connection string). Please make sure to test your [mcve] before posting it.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers It is true. At the time of editing the connection string I have deleted the double quotes. I'll have more attention next time.

Comment: @drakin8564 Also change the MySQL configuration file, but it is still returning the incorrect value.

Comment: Did you restart/reload the server after making that change?

Comment: Yes. After the modification I rebooted the MySQL service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution to this case.
The MySQL ODBC driver 5.3.6 or later does not assimilate the configuration of the 'max_execution_time' variable on MySQL server 5.7.4 or later.
I solved my problem by installing version 5.1 of the MySQL ODBC driver.